# SQL: Keep subquery order in outer query

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, psql

I am having issues trying to combine `DISTINCT` & `ORDER BY`. I have a `Users` table with the following attributes `id, name` & I have a `Purchases` table with the following attributes `id,user_id,date_purchased,returned`

I want to retrieve all unique `Users` that have a `returned` `Purchase` sorted by `date_purchased`.

Here is some sample data

```
Users
id | name 
---+-----------
 1 | Bob
 2 | John
 3 | Bill
 4 | Frank
 5 | Fred
 6 | Al

Purchases
      id |      user_id     |  startdate | returned 
    -----+------------------+------------+---------------
     100 | 1                | 2015-02-06 |          true
     101 | 1                | 2015-01-06 |          true
     102 | 1                | 2015-02-05 |          false
     103 | 2                | 2015-02-05 |          false
     104 | 2                | 2015-02-05 |          false
     105 | 3                | 2015-01-05 |          true
     106 | 3                | 2015-02-04 |          true
     107 | 4                | 2015-01-07 |          true
     108 | 5                | 2015-02-05 |          false
     109 | 6                | 2015-02-07 |          false
     110 | 6                | 2015-01-05 |          true
```

The result should be the following user id's `1,3,4,6`

Here is the query I wrote

```
SELECT DISTINCT (id) FROM (
   SELECT users.id as id, purchases.startdate FROM
   users INNER JOIN purchases on users.id=purchases.id
   WHERE returned=true
   ORDER BY startdate )
```

This query correctly returns the results; however it is in the incorrect order. Reading other answers I found that you can't maintain the subquery ordering. I tried to move the ordering to the outer query; however, `startdate` would also need to be present in the select query & that is not what I want

Comment: It is unclear what question your query is intended to answer.  There is a `startdate` associated with each purchase, and one user may return multiple purchases.  By *which* `startdate`, then, do you wish to order the results?

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the subquery and use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT u.id as id
FROM users u INNER JOIN
     purchases p
     on u.id = p.id
WHERE returned = true
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY MIN(startdate);
```

You can only rely on the result set being in a particular order when you use `ORDER BY` for the *outermost* `SELECT`.  There is no guarantee of ordering in any other case.

As a note:  ordering usually does work with subquery (sadly, because many people look at the results from some queries and generalize to all of them).  The problem in this case is the `distinct`.  It rearranges the data (i.e. sorts it) to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's script gives you the data you want, but to answer your question of how to maintain a subquery's order, you can pull the column you want to order by out of the subquery and *then* order by it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (id), innerTable.startdate FROM (
   SELECT users.id as id, purchases.startdate FROM
   users INNER JOIN purchases on users.id=purchases.id
   WHERE returned=true) as innerTable
   ORDER BY innerTable.startdate
```

Comment: They want distinct IDs only, while your query is pulling distinct combinations of `id` and `startdate`. (Enclosing `id` in brackets doesn't tell the database server that you want only `id` to be distinct: `DISTINCT` is always applied to entire rows.)